# Code first initial create with MVC identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I'm creating initial migration using

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

But then when I'm updating my database tables from IdentityDbContext are not created so I get exceptions.

So how do I create migration for AspNetUser tables from IdentityDbContext?

Regards teamol

Comment: Are you trying to update your database with "Update-Database" command in package manager console?

Comment: What exceptions are you getting? Do you have a separate context for your application context? Does it inherit IdentityDbContext?

Comment: Yes I'm calling Update-Database from package managere console. I have one context  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>. I get exception while generating table which has a FK to AspNetUser table that AspNetUser table does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom fields to your AspNetUser table in your IdentityModels.cs file.

First add your custom values ito ApplicationUser class in IdentityModels:

```
namespace YourProjectName.Models
{
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string NameSurname { get; set; }
       public string ProfilePhotoRoute { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
   }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

After that, enter "Add-Migration NewMigration" command in package manager console.

Finally, enter "Update-Database" command in package manager console.

If your connection string -which is stated in web.config- is true, you can update succesfully your database with this way.

Comment: I know how to add custom fields to AspNetUser table. That is not the problem the problem is that when I call Update-Database from package manager console all my tables are created except for AspNetUser tables (AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUsers)

Comment: How many connection strings do you have? And what is your "DefaultConnection" connection string?